# How to open a dialog from navigation drawer?

Tags: android, dialog

```
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_create_group);
        dialog.show();
```

It run fine when I open dialog from activity. But when I try to open the dialog from the navigation drawer, I receive this exception:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(Your_Class_Activity.this);
             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_create_group);
            dialog.show();
```

May it help you!